# How I use PathExpander in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

How I use PathExpander in neo4j? Can I create Path from Node on each iteration or it's wrong?

TIA.

UPD.

```
                         StandardExpander se = StandardExpander.DEFAULT;
                         se.add(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("TRANSPORT"),  Direction.OUTGOING);
                         se.add(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("TRANSPORT_LONGER"),  Direction.OUTGOING);
                         se.addRelationshipFilter(myFilter);
```

I must create `myFilter` manually? Thanks.

UPD#2.
There is another question: how I use result of expanding as follow:

```
Expansion ss = se.expand(graphDb.getNodeById(1));
```

(`Expansion` class is closed and don't visible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I use Traversal.expanderForTypes(...) and a number of relationships types.